# Integrability with respect to different measures

Tags: measure-theory

i'm doing an integration exercise and i'm new to the subject and i'm kind of struggling it is as follow

> We consider the application $g$ : $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x)=\frac{1}{x} if x >0$ and $ g(x)=0 $ otherwise.
> We note $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on ($\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})}$ and $\mu$ the image measure of the Lebesgue measure by $g$, defined by $\mu(A)=\lambda(g^-1(A))$ for $A \in \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})}$. We remind that for all function $h$ : $\mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \rightarrow ([0,\infty],\mathcal{B([0,\infty])})$ measruable
> \begin{align} \int_{\mathbb{R}} hd\mu=\int_{\mathbb{R}} h \circ g d\lambda
> \end{align}
> We note $\nu= \sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\delta_n$ the counting measure over $\mathbb{N}$. For $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, let $f_{\alpha}(x)=x^{-\alpha} 1_{[1,\infty[}(x), x\in \mathbb{R}.$

I first have to show that $f$ is measurable but since it is not continuous (i believe) i have to go back to the definition but i'm kind of stuck.

Then we have to give a necessary and sufficient condition over $\alpha$ under which $f_{\alpha}$ is integrable

> a) with respect to $ \lambda$, $\mu$ and $ \nu$.

Any hints or helping hand would be greatly appreciated thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f_\alpha$ is not continuous, but it is continuous for $x<1$ and for $x>1$. This suffices to prove that the function is measurable (as for any measurable $A$ we have $B=A\cap[1,\infty)$, $C=A\cap(-\infty,1)$ are measureable and thus $f_\alpha^{-1}(A)=f_\alpha^{-1}(B)\cup f_\alpha^{-1}(C)$ is measurable).

Now when is $f_\alpha$ integrable? For $\lambda$ we know that this is the case if and only if $\alpha>1$ (if $\alpha<1$ you get $\int_1^\infty x^{-\alpha} = (\alpha-1)(1 - \lim_{x\to\infty} x^{1-\alpha}) = \alpha$, if $\alpha < 1$ we get the same, but the limit does not exists, for $\alpha=1$ we get $\lim_{x\to\infty}\log(x)$, which also does not exist.

For $\mu$ we want $f\circ g$ to be integrable by $\lambda$, that is $x^\alpha 1_{[1,\infty)}(1/x)=x^\alpha 1_{(0,1]}(x)$. So when is
$$ \int_0^1 x^\alpha\,\mathrm d\lambda$$
finite? We know this is the case if and only if $\alpha >-1$ (similar reasoning to $\lambda$ case).

Then for $\nu$ you want to have that $\int_\mathbb R f_\alpha\,\mathrm d\nu = \sum_{n\in\mathbb N} f_\alpha(n)$ is finite. So when is
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-\alpha} $$
finite? We know again that this is exactly the case iff $\alpha>1$.

Comment: Thank you, this is clear. :)